# db2 cross platform function/variable?

Tags: db2, db2-luw, db2-zos, db2-midrange

Is there a db2 function/procedure/variable that can be used to determine what platform a data source origins from? sysibm.sysdummy1 exists, so I assume that this is Db2, but some of the SQL does not look right according to LUW syntax. Is there an easy way to figure out via SQL what platform a data source origins from?

Comment: Depends on the client you're using

Comment: [It doesn't look promising.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821795/how-to-check-db2-version) :( They do offer a [reference for cross platform development](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/hybriddatamanagement/blogs/lynn-chou/2018/10/01/the-sql-reference-for-cross-platform-development) that apparently highlights the differences.

Comment: @mustaccio, all I know is that I can put sql in a cdata tag and get the result back. I would like to ask a query that can identify the DBMS. If there is no such mechanism, perhaps there is some catalog table that only exists in LUW, some other that only exists on Z and similar for i.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a very open-ended question, as there is no sure-fire method to determine the server version and platform. You'll need to apply some heuristics.

In **Db2 for LUW** (and only LUW) since v 10.1 there's a system view `dbmcfg` that can return the server version:

```
select value from sysibmadm.dbmcfg where name = 'release'
```

so if it succeeds you'll be sure it's Db2 for LUW of certain release level. Similarly, since v 9.7 you can query `sysibmadm.env_inst_info` (or first search for it in `syscat.tables`).

Another indicator of Db2 for LUW is the presence of some Oracle-compatible views since v.9.7, e.g. `syspublic.dual` or `sysibmadm.all_objects`.

A good indicator of **Db2 for z/OS** would be the presence of mainframe-specific catalog tables, e.g. `sysibm.locations` or `sysibm.syscopy`, which go back to v9 at least.

The presence of catalog views in the `QSYS` and `QSYS2` schemas, e.g. `QSYS2.TABLES`, will indicate **Db2 for i** (AS/400).

Neither Db2 for z/OS nor Db2 for i have the `SYSCAT` schema views.